# Cosa significa "mento volontario"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La madre*, di Grazia Deledda, ho letto:

> Non aveva aperto labbra, ma un tremito lieve tentava nuovamente di scomporle il **mento volontario**. D’un tratto salì nella sua cameretta e si vestì in fretta per andare anche lei in chiesa: e anche lei si stringeva la cintura e camminava forte; prima di avviarsi non dimenticò di ricacciar via le galline, di tirare indietro sul fuoco la caffettiera, di chiudere le porte; infine si cinse bene sul mento e sulla bocca il lembo della sciarpa perché il tremito, per quanti sforzi ella facesse per frenarlo, le durava ancora.

Ho cercato l'aggettivo "volontario" su alcuni dizionari, ma non capisco del tutto bene il senso dell'espressione "mento volontario" che appare in questo passaggio. Ha qualcosa a che vedere con i cosiddetti "muscoli volontari"?

Comment: Curioso. A orecchio, sembrerebbe una variazione sull'abituale locuzione “mento volitivo”.

Comment: @DaG: Non sono sicura di cogliere il significato di "mento volitivo". Da quanto si spiega sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI21/GDLI_21_ocr_1001.pdf&parola=mento%20volitivo) devo capire che si tratta di un mento con un aspetto che manifesta decisione, determinazione, forza di volontà?

Comment: @DaG: Ecco, guarda [qui](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI21/GDLI_21_ocr_1005.pdf&parola=), dove si spiega che "volontario" può avere il significato di "volitivo" (riferito a un tratto del viso) e ci sono esempi letterari di "bocca volontaria", "fronte alta e volontaria", "viso [...] con un aspetto più volontario". Sembra che la tua intuizione abbia trovato la risposta giusta.

Comment: Ho visto che "mento volitivo" appare sul [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mento).

Comment: E adesso... qualche madrelingua italiano/a potrebbe scrivere una risposta facendo uso di queste fonti?

Comment: Forse il più famoso “mento volitivo” è quello del capoccione… ;-)

Comment: @egreg: Cos'è il capoccione?

Comment: Un famoso dittatore degli anni 20-40.

Answer (score 1):

Preferirei una risposta scritta da un/a madrelingua italiano/a. Tuttavia, cerco di raccogliere qui quello che si è detto nei commenti riguardo alla domanda.

Alla voce "volontàrio" del [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI21/GDLI_21_ocr_1005.pdf&parola=) si trova questa accezione, che è quella adatta al contesto del testo della domanda:

> 7.  Ant.  e  letter.  Che  è  dotato  di  una  volontà  forte  e 
>   determinata; volitivo. 
>   [...]
>         - Che è segno esteriore, fisiognomico di tale atteg­giamento (un tratto del viso). 
>         *Gozzano*, I-523: Rivedo... la  bella testa candida sfavillante in 
>   un  raggio  di  sole  obliquo,  la  bocca  volontaria,  l’occhio  azzurro giovanile. 
>   *Moretti*,  IV-625:  Tempie... frequentemente  pulsanti, fronte  alta  e  volontaria,  palpebre  verdastre. *C.  Levi*,  6-47:  Era una  donna  di  una  trentina  d’anni,  piccola  e  grassoccia.  Di  viso assomigliava  al  fratello,  ma  con  un  aspetto  più  volontario e appassionato.

Quindi, un "mento volontario" sarebbe un mento che conferisce al viso un aspetto che mostra una "volontà forte e determinata".

Da quanto ho potuto capire dai commenti, un'espressione abituale nell'italiano attuale con un significato simile sarebbe "mento volitivo". Cercando "volitivo" sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI21/GDLI_21_ocr_1001.pdf&parola=mento%20volitivo) si può leggere questa definizione, che va accompagnata appunto di un esempio letterario di uso di "mento volitivo":

> - Che  manifesta la  decisione,  la  forza  di  volontà,  la 
>   determinazione (i tratti del viso, l’espressione). 
>   *Monelli*, 2-362:  Avevo  ancora  la  moneta  in  mano,  guardai l’arguto profilo, il mento volitivo.

Infine, alla voce "mento" del [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mento) si trova

> *m. volitivo*, di forma piuttosto quadrata, considerato segno di forza di carattere